# What is the maximum portals per mission?

Tags: ingress

I want to create a very difficult mission with 200-400 portals. Creating such a mission is a lengthy task. I want to plan ahead how many and which portals I can use, because the layout would be very different if I could use only 50 of 400 planned portals.

> What is the maximum of portals I can use in a mission?

---

---

### update

The mission is up, you can see it [here](http://missions.qry.me/linkamppath/).

I have added 100 portals and then changed their objective and description using* a script, otherwise I would have been still doing it, see yourself:

```
var scope = angular.element($("#waypoints")).scope();
scope.$apply(function(){
    var child = scope.$$childTail;

    do {
        var wp = child.waypoint;
        //console.log(child.$index, wp._poi.title);

        wp._show_custom_description = true;
        wp.custom_description = "N/A";
        wp.objective.type = "INSTALL_MOD"
    } while ((child.$first == false) && (child = child.$$prevSibling))
})
```

*use at *Waypoints* page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While fiddling with the angular object in the mission-author tool I came across some fancy properties.

From what can be seen there it is apparent that the **maximum waypoints is 100**.

[image]